# crash if CFDictionaryRef does not exist

Tags: objective-c, macos

i have an issue when disconnecting ethernet-cable from computer or just turned off ethernet. in this case some entrys do not exist and my app would crash.
so i tryed to find out how to prevent and just found **CFDictionaryContainsKey**, but this does not prevent the error. Anybody who knows an workaround which is also working ***lower than osx 10.6*** ?

```
- (NSString *)checkNetworkInterface
{
    SCDynamicStoreRef ds = SCDynamicStoreCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("myapp"), NULL, NULL);
    CFDictionaryRef dr = SCDynamicStoreCopyValue(ds, CFSTR("State:/Network/Global/IPv4"));
    Boolean ck = CFDictionaryContainsKey( dr, CFSTR("PrimaryInterface"));
    NSString *interfaceString;
    if (ck) {
        CFStringRef interface = CFDictionaryGetValue(dr, CFSTR("PrimaryInterface"));
        interfaceString = [NSString stringWithString:( NSString *)interface ];
    } else {
        interfaceString = [NSString stringWithString:@"" ];
    }
    CFRelease(dr);
    CFRelease(ds);
    return interfaceString;
}
```

if "State:/Network/Global/IPv4" does not exist, app crashes :(

Comment: How are you invoking `CFDictionaryContainsKey`?

Comment: `Boolean ck = CFDictionaryContainsKey( dr, CFSTR("PrimaryInterface"));` it can detect key's but not Dictionarys itself or?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a full example of the way you used `CFDictionaryContainsKey`?

Comment: `CFDictionaryContainsKey` makes no sense here i think, because the key cant exist if the dictionary does not exist. so how to check if a dictionary exist. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation for [`SCDynamicStoreCopyValue()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/SCDynamicStore/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SCDynamicStoreCopyValue) states:

> **Return Value**: The value associated with the specified key, or NULL if no value was located or if an error occurred. You must release the returned value.

`CFDictionaryContainsKey()` attempts to inspect the passed-in dictionary; if it's NULL, you crash with a NULL pointer dereference. You also shouldn't `CFRelease()` a NULL pointer.

To correct this, just add a NULL check before calling `CFDictionaryContainsKey()`.

```
NSString *interfaceString;
if(dr != NULL && CFDictionaryContainsKey(dr, CFSTR("PrimaryInterface")))
{
  CFStringRef interface = CFDictionaryGetValue(dr, CFSTR("PrimaryInterface"));
  ...
  CFRelease(dr);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to check whether `dr == NULL` and abort if so. Apologies if this is a little obvious, but you're not doing it here and it seems like it would ward off the crash.

Comment: well i checked this in some test `dr==NULL` but did not work, maybe because of my wrong positioned `CFRelease(dr)`. with other words you can just release what is existing. hmm?